# AngularJS Form Rendering from .NET Web API Models

Tags: c#, .net, angularjs, forms, asp.net-web-api

I have C# models that can require the UI to render different form options depending on the model.

For example:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string SSN { get; set; }    
}

public class Employee : Person
{
    public string BadgeId { get; set; }
    public GroupEnum Group { get; set; }    
}
```

I want a service that will return the model description given a class name.  It would need to account for things like enumerations and decorators for things like a password input type for the SSN property.

Is there tool out there already that does something like this? feel like this is pretty common.